# Ordering an ArrayList with duplicate Strings

Tags: java, android, arraylist, charts, duplicates

Well i have an ArrayList with some strings in it
and i want to get the number of duplicates that each string has and order them from the highest number to the lowest like this :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("a");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");
    list.add("b");
    list.add("c");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");
    list.add("a");

    Set<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<String>(list);
    for (String temp : uniqueSet) {

        System.out.println(temp + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, temp));
    }
```

and i want to store the top 10 values for a ***Charting*** project so i don't just need to print them, i need to put the result somewhere, that for example when i call "a" it gives me 3.

Comment: why would calling "a" give "3"?

Comment: a more useful data structure would be a map where you can keep the count along with the character as the key.

Comment: oh, I see why. but what has it got to do with android?

Comment: @ItamarGreen as i wrote , my charting project is for an android app and i'm using MPchart android

Comment: oh, now I see. Have you tested my answer on an android platform? I myself haven't developed in android in a while so I'm quite eager about this XD.

Comment: @ArashSM79 If you want top 10 strings with highest number of duplicates in a map then check out this [link](http://www.java2novice.com/java-interview-programs/sort-a-map-by-value/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well as some of you mentioned OOP , i created a model class with 2 variables and getter setters and i put the 'temp' in name and 'Collections.frequency(list, temp)' in the Fre and then i tried listing some objects and ordered them with the following code:

```
   Collections.sort(jList, new Comparator<GetJournalsModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(GetJournalsModel a1, GetJournalsModel a2) {
            return a1.getFre() - a2.getFre();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To map a string to an int (letter to frequency) you can use a Map object:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("a");
list.add("a");
list.add("a");
Collections.sort(list);
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (String string : list) {
    if(!map.containsKey(string)){
        map.put(string, Collections.frequency(list, string));
    }
}
```

and then the map contains the wanted information.

A HashMap is a convenient way to store information which has unique keys and for each key there's a value.

Comment: don't think Collections.sort is really required out here.

Comment: collections.sort is just another way to make sure that the keys remain unique. but I agree, not very necessary

Comment: @brso05 incrementing a value in a map is very cumbersome and very inconvenient.

Comment: well I would, but the question specifically asks for an arraylist. I have no idea if it's needed for a method in a different part of the program

Comment: using just maps is kinda easy and more used approach for frequency counters. Also it doesn't rely on Collections.frequency() which isn't a very cost effective implementation.

Comment: Well I guess it's better than my own implementation.

Comment: @ItamarGreen yeah, map is a good idea but the problem is, that how i can get for example the top 10 strings with the highest duplicates ?

Comment: a map object can return the values as a Collection.

Comment: well for your specific problem, i would guess another solution would be to use a list of objects where the object has attributes char character and int count. you can maintain a list of these objects and keep on updating counts when you find duplicates. for the class you can implement a comparator and enable sorting on count and then just pick the first 10 objects from your list.

Comment: that's exactly like a map, only with a bit of OOP thrown in.

Comment: true .. the basic idea is pretty much the same but he gets the freedom to sort over values and still maintain the relation with the key which is the character in this case. just simplifies things a little

Comment: Using a map doesn't bind you to key value relations. It's more flexibly than that. It's not unlike Dictionary in C#

Comment: map implementation gets a little weird in his case because he eventually needs to sort on the count of characters and then report the characters with 10 max counts which indicates trying to find a key through the value :P

Comment: yeah...not arguing with you. just an alternate suggestion which might be easier to implement in this case. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125644/discussion-between-itamar-green-and-digidude).

Answer (score 0):

A guava [Multiset](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained) would be a nice fit, it works like a Set but records a count of elements.

```
Multiset<String> letters = ImmutableMultiset.of("a", "b", "d", "b", "a", "a", "a", "i", "f");
// [a x 4, b x 2, d, f, i]

letters.count("a"); 
// 4
```

Getting the top counting elements isn't too hard either.

```
Multiset<String> top3 = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
letters.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted((l1, l2) -> Integer.compare(l2.getCount(), l1.getCount()))
    .limit(3)
    .forEach(e -> top3.add(e.getElement(), e.getCount()));
// [a x 4, b x 2, d]
```